# Is every type-theoretic function ℕ → A extensionally equal to one written in terms of the ℕ-eliminator

Tags: type-theory, category-theory, natural-numbers

In Category Theory the Natural Numbers object ℕ has the universal mapping-out property that tells us how to build arrows out of ℕ into an arbitrary object A. But it doesn't say that *every* arrow `ℕ -> A` is equal to the "eliminator" arrow for some pair of arrows `init :  → A, step : A → A`. Is it true in some of the standard dependent Type Theories, say, in extensional MLTT or OTT?

Edit: as pointed out by Trebor, in the original formulation there are functions that can't be represented via the eliminator. But with an enhanced eliminator Trebor's example works:
[image]

Comment: Consider the function $f(0)=f(1)=1$, $f(n)=2$ otherwise. This cannot be written in that form because you can't have `step 1 = 1` and `step 1 = 2` at the same time.

Comment: You can still express this function using the sliding window trick, but it is no longer of the eliminator-form.

Comment: That's not true.

Assuming the following syntax:

`⟨init, step⟩ : ℕ → A`

We have:

`⟨1, ⟨1, const 2⟩⟩ 0 = 1`
`⟨1, ⟨1, const 2⟩⟩ 1 = ⟨1, const 2⟩ 0 = 1`
`⟨1, ⟨1, const 2⟩⟩ 2 = ⟨1, const 2⟩ 1 = 2`

That is, `step` itself can be recursive.

Comment: Did you check in a proof assistant?

Comment: Ah, I see it now. My example is wrong. `step` needs access to the natural number relative to which we compute the step. Then it works...
`init :  → A`
`step : ℕ → A → A`

Comment: @Trebor edited my question

Comment: Note that if you are given an eliminator `elim` which takes in only the weaker `step : A → A`, you can implement the stronger one by using `elim` at type `A × ℕ` and arrows built from the universal property of `ℕ` and the product.

Comment: It is considered bad form to post pictures of code. You're behaving like my children.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I just wanted me some semantic highlighting :) But agreed 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With function extensionality this is trivially true, because `f = elim (f 0) (\n _ -> f (suc n))`. Without function extensionality I suspect it is not true, but constructing a countermodel would be hard because there is no recursion, just a single case split.

Comment: The [parametric exceptional model](https://inria.hal.science/hal-01840643/document) gives you a simple counter model of MLTT to this. In this model, constant functions `fun (_ : nat) => t` are provably different from their inductive η-expansion `fun (n : nat) => match n with 0 => t | S _ => t end`.

Comment: Imagine if they were unprovably different!